# Google Core Reporting API v4 authenticate with services account

Tags: javascript, google-analytics-api, google-reporting-api

I'm migrating from Google Core Reporting API v3 to v4. In Google Docs, I can't find a way how to authenticate with a service account token like you can in v3 with Javascript. Is this possible in v4?

Comment: Service accounts are not supported with JavaScript you will either need to use Oauth2 or go with a server sided language.

Comment: If you'll compare [Authorizing Requests v3](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/authorization#authorizing_requests) and [Authorizing Requests v4](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/authorization#authorizing_requests), there are no significant differences in authorizing request so it is possible that authenticating service account is applicable in v4.(server)

Comment: Minimal changes would be applied as v4 supports v3's syntax for segments and filters, check the [migration guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/migration) for additional information. Hope this helps.

Comment: If you are interested in querying the API with a service account and rendering it with JavaScript or the embed API you should take a look at the open source demo of [server side auth](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/server-side-authorization/)